# OSX - How to auto Close Terminal window after the "exit" command executed.

Tags: macos, terminal

When I'm done with Terminal, I want to exit it. Right now, I have three options:

1. killall Terminal. It will end the process, but rather abruptly. I don't think this is the best idea.
2. Call exit. I've changed the settings so exit closes Terminal. The app still appears open in the Dock though, and doesn't do what I want it to do.
3. Right click>Quit. However, this isn't a Terminal command to exit it.

So now, what is the way I should exit and close Terminal? I've heard something about osascript but I'm not too sure. I want to exit and close, so that Terminal is no longer open, both as a window and as a process.

Comment: Like `kill`, `killall` defaults to sending `SIGTERM`, which can be caught. Some programs catch it, clean up after themselves and exit gracefully. No idea if `Terminal.app` is among them. However, I suspect this would be better on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or Super User in a pinch as it does not seem to have any programming content.

Comment: I think the question would be better phrased “How to Quit Terminal after the last shell exits?”.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close Terminal window from within shell script (Unix)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798641/close-terminal-window-from-within-shell-script-unix)

Answer (score 289):

in Terminal.app

Preferences > Profiles > (Select a Profile) > Shell.

on 'When the shell exits' chosen 'Close the window'

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada wouldnt be too terrible if you wanted to use that space to feed user output but otherwise insanikov's answer would have done quife fine for me

Comment: Obvious and clean, perfect.

Comment: In the newer versions of OS X, this option can be found under 'Preferences > Profiles > (Select a Profile) > Shell.

Comment: You can use the link for more and step wise step info  https://www.cnet.com/news/terminal-tip-close-windows-after-clean-exit/

Comment: You can also select all the profiles, and make the change to all at once.

Comment: In macOS Sierra 10.13.5, there is also the option "Close if the shell exited cleanly." This option may also be present in earlier versions of the OS.

Comment: On Mac OS Monterey this doesn't work. It only closes the window, but you still need to press Cmd-Q to quit the app, or in other words, as the original question noted: "The app still appears open in the Dock though, and doesn't do what I want it to do."

Answer (score 49):

Actually, you should set a config on your Terminal, when your Terminal is up press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> then you will see below screen:

[image]

Then press shell tab and you will see below screen:

[image]

Now select `Close if the shell exited cleanly` for **When the shell exits**.

By the above config each time with `exit` command the Terminal will close but won't quit.

Comment: This doesn't solve much in my case. Indeed, the initial window does close, but then a fresh terminal window opens.

Comment: @Lethargos, what? I didn't understand your issue!, please explain a little bit more.

Comment: I run an app (firefox) as a shell script, because I want to choose add a cli parameter (-P profile_name). In order for it to work in finder, I add the '.command' extention. I set the 'close if the shell exited cleanly' option. The consequence of that is that the initial window exists, indeed, but the terminal (actually) remains open. That's it. (mbp m1, monterey 12.0.1)

Comment: @Lethargos, it's a very important case, I think it is better to post a question about this issue, the answer is using `&` for closing in the `.command` file. I can help you. if you are agreed, post a question with enough explain and screenshot, I will send the answer in full description there with a good example.

Comment: I am using `&` and `nohup` at that. But yes, I was planning to post a question about this, as I still haven't found anything else on the internet. So I'll do it soon :)

Comment: I've posted my question :)

Answer (score 38):

How about the good old Command-Q?

Comment: He does mean command Q. Is this a good method though? It seems no different than killall to me.

Comment: @darksteel: Command-Q is the proper way to close an app on the Mac.  Doing a killall is probably OK as well since the app is told to terminate cleanly.

Comment: Yeah I meant to type "Command" but it came out as Ctrl. I'd say it's a case of PEBBAF (Problem exist between brain and fingertips).

Comment: kill/killall is not a good way to terminate an application, generally. That could discard unsaved state, or save state that doesn’t correctly reflect how the application would look had you Quit it. Mac OS X does have a “Sudden Termination” feature where programs can indicate when they’re in a state where it’s safe to kill them (with SIGKILL, in fact), and if you checked the state of Terminal with Activity Monitor to verify that it’s safe to kill it first (show the “Sudden Termination” column and look for “Yes”), you could then do so, but you can’t easily automate that workflow.

Comment: We can always use command-Q after exit, which closes all process and then closes the terminal.

Answer (score 33):

In the Terminal app, **Preference** >> **Profiles** tab.

Select the **Shell** tab on the right.
[image]

You can choose **Never** Ask before closing to suppress the warning.

Comment: I achieved this with `When shell exits:` "close the window"

Comment: This answer didn't work for me by choosing "Never". However @Anup's comment about "Close the window" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 18):

You could use AppleScript through the `osascript` command:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
```

Comment: I hadn't tried the osascript command, but there's two issues I have with this:

1. It's rather long for a command to quit. Shouldn't it be simpler? I like in Windows how exit terminates command prompt.

2. It still prompts me to quit Terminal. I want it to just go through the motions. A window came up asking if I really wanted to quit.

Comment: @darksteel: 1. Add an alias in your `.bashrc` (or equivalent if you use a different shell). I'm still thinking of an answer to 2.

Comment: I'm thinking command Q works best. But I'm curious as to how to setup an alias properly. There's a few commands like "ping google.com" that I do often enough that I might prefer an alias.

Comment: @darksteel: This is way overthinking it, but to prevent 2, you could start a daemonized process that sleeps about a second, and then `exit` after starting the daemonized process. After the daemonized process has waited a second, it could call `osascript` as described.

Comment: @darksteel: You can also trigger a keypress through `osascript`: `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down`. This will probably have the issue though, too.

Comment: @darksteel: I just tried the daemonize method, and apparently `osascript` doesn't like being run from a daemon. Honestly I think `killall` is just fine.

Comment: Doesn't killall try to close the app properly anyways? I'm pretty sure it tells the app to close and lets it try to close, and only abruptly ends the process if the process can't terminate itself. I would assume that if there's no problems, it will terminate properly and then it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 12):

In a terminal window, you can type:

```
kill -9 $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=)
```

This will kill the Terminal application process, which is the parent of the parent of the current process, as seen by the kill command.

To close a Terminal window from within a running script, you need to go up one more level in the process hierarchy like this:

```
kill -9 $(ps -p $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=) -o ppid=)
```

Comment: FYI, this solution kills other terminal windows too.

Comment: And don't use `kill -9` unless you know other signals won't work.

Answer (score 10):

`osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"w\" using command down"`

This simulates a <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> keypress.

If you want Terminal to quit completely you can use:
`osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"q\" using command down"`

This doesn't give any errors and makes the Terminal stop cleanly.

Answer (score 9):

I 've been using `ctrl + d`. It throws you out into the destination where You've started the sqlite3 command in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this convoluted command, which does not trigger a warning about terminating its own process:
`osascript -e "do shell script \"osascript -e \\\"tell application \\\\\\\"Terminal\\\\\\\" to quit\\\" &> /dev/null &\""; exit`

This command is quite long, so you could define an alias (such as `quit`) in your bash profile:
`alias quit='osascript -e "do shell script \"osascript -e \\\"tell application \\\\\\\"Terminal\\\\\\\" to quit\\\" &> /dev/null &\""; exit'`

This would allow you to simply type `quit` into terminal without having to fiddle with any other settings.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `osascript` command in your code as icktoofay mentioned: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'`

Then, open Terminal preferences, go to Settings > Shell, and set "Prompt before closing:" to "Never." Terminal should now quit completely (not remain open in your dock) and ignore the prompt before quitting. If you have only one Terminal window open and the `osascript` command is your last line of code, it should wait for whatever command you ran before to finish.

This would not be ideal if you are running scripts in the same window or other windows in the background (for instance, you may run a command in the background and continue using the current window for other commands if the first command is followed by an ampersand); be careful!

If you wrap the `osascript` code in a shell script file, you can probably call it with whatever pithy file-name you give it---as long as it is in Terminal's search path (run `echo $PATH` to see where Terminal looks for scripts).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did for a command I just wrote. I wanted to be able to create a "shortcut" to the Backup directory for Apple Configurator that worked on different computers, but since it's relative to the user's home directory, I needed to make it a `.command` file. Here are the contents:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

open "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup"
(sleep 0.1 ; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit') &
```

Comment: This worked the cleanest for me with no warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using

quit -n terminal

at the end of my scripts. You have to have the terminal set to never prompt in preferences

So Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Shell 
**When the shell exits**
Close the window
**Prompt before closing**
Never

Answer (score 1):

## Create a script:

`cat ~/exit.scpt`

### like this:

- Note: If there is only one window, just quit the application, else simulate `command + w` to close the tab)

`tell application "Terminal"
    set WindowNum to get window count
    if WindowNum = 1 then
        quit
    else
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "w" using command down
    end if
end tell`

## Then add a alias in your *shrc

just like `vi ~/.bashrc` or `zshrc` (anything else?)

add it:
`alias exit="osascript ~/exit.scpt"`

## And source the ~/.bashrc or reopen your terminal.app

Answer (score 0):

I tried several variations of the answers here.  No matter what I try, I can always find a use case where the user is prompted to close Terminal.

Since my script is a simple (`drutil -drive 2 tray open` -- to open a specific DVD drive), the user does **not** need to see the Terminal window while the script runs.

My solution was to turn the script into an app, which runs the script without displaying a Terminal window.  The added benefit is that any terminal windows that are already open stay open, and if none are open, then Terminal doesn't stay resident after the script ends.  It doesn't seem to launch Terminal at all to run the bash script.

I followed these instructions to turn my script into an app: https://superuser.com/a/1354541/162011

Answer (score -2):

If this is a Mac you type 'exit' then press return.